# Use Babelify with Browserify Globally / Global in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify, babelify

### Background:

I have several vanilla JS projects with files up to 25 000 lines / single file in which I would like to use ES6 capabilities + require so I can make the code more readable. OS X guy by the way

### Possible solution:

I could make up a package.json and use a webpack for each project, but I would prefer if I do not do that.

### What I have done so far:

Install browserify globally

```
sudo npm install -g browserify
```

setup a watcher in **PhpStorm**

[image: phpstorm config]

global browserify path

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js
```

arguments

```
$FilePath$
-o
$FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js
```

all works fine, and if I have a require in my code

```
var foo = require('./inc/_dependency-functionality');
```

✅ it will bundle just right and the required external files will get bundle inside a single file

BUT, ideally, I would like to have it so that I can use ES6 import / export functions, which may say I need babelify

doing this

```
sudo npm install -g browserify
```

and using

```
$FilePath$
-o
$FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js
-t [ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babelify --presets [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/preset-env ] ]
```

❌ will not actually babelify the script

I'm kind of stuck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do it

```
$FilePath$
-o
$FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js
-t [ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babelify/index.js --presets [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/preset-env ] ]
```

Babelify should be appended by **/index.js**

and then you can actually lose the presets, if you have .babelrc in the home of your user library ( babel searches for .babelrc recursively on top )

```
$FilePath$
-o
$FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js
-t [ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babelify/index.js ]
```

Also, make sure your files are named **file.source.js** not **file.babel** as I had them, as the transpiling will not start for unknown files